# L2PT VPN connection restricts internet connection

Tags: windows, connection, vpn, windows-11

I am currently working from home and connecting to my work PC via L2PT VPN connection and Remote Desktop Connection. It is working perfectly fine on Windows 10. However, If I do a fresh install on Windows 11, the connection is fine for a couple of hours and then for some reason I can not get more then 1/2 mbpr when connected to the VPN, while before that I am getting around 100 mbpr. I have done all the guides that are available on the Internet, but nothing is helping.

My laptop is Lenovo Leagion 5 pro.

Please help.

I tried different solutions found online, but they were for reducing the need of strong internet connection for Remote Desktop Connection and in my case I barely can load google.com